# R sqldf - index inside / outside a loop

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm using the sqldf function to repeatedly join a subset of a table against itself.  The repeat process is happening inside a for loop.  I've read that adding an index can improve performance of these joins [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/improve-the-efficiency-in-joining-data-with-index/).

My question is - if I'm repeatedly doing this in a loop, does this mean I have to recreate the index each time the loop executes or is there a way to have the index 'persist' outside the loop but be used inside the loop?

In other words I've only seen this version :

```
for(i in 1:10){
   df1 <- sqldf(c('create index...','select * from table1'))
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
df1 <- sqldf('create index...') # create index outside of loop

for(i in 1:10){
   df2 <- sqldf('select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1')
}
```

EDIT:

```
> sqldf() 
NULL
> 
> sqldf("create index idx on iris(Species)") ## 
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
> sqldf("select count(*) from main.iris where Species = 'virginica'") ##
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such table: main.iris
> sqldf("select count(*) from main.iris where Species <> 'virginica'") ##
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  no such table: main.iris
> 
> sqldf()
<SQLiteConnection>
  Path: :memory:
  Extensions: TRUE
>
```

EDIT_2:

```
> sqldf() 
NULL
> # close an old connection if it exists
>    if (!is.null(getOption("sqldf.connection"))) sqldf()
> sqldf() 
<SQLiteConnection>
  Path: :memory:
  Extensions: TRUE
> sqldf("create index idx on iris(Species)") ## 
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
> sqldf("select count(*) from main.iris where Species = 'virginica'") ##
  count(*)
1       50
> sqldf("select count(*) from main.iris where Species <> 'virginica'") ##
  count(*)
1      100
> sqldf() 
NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The no argument form of `sqldf` can be used for opening and closing a connection so that intermediate `sqldf` statements can all use the same connection.

Note that we can refer to the version of the table already uploaded by referring to table `x` as `main.x`; otherwise, each `sqldf` will try to upload it again.  You could also consider adding the `verbose = TRUE` argument to the statements marked ## to see what is going on.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf() 

sqldf("create index idx on iris(Species)") ## 
sqldf("select count(*) from main.iris where Species = 'virginica'") ##
sqldf("select count(*) from main.iris where Species <> 'virginica'") ##

sqldf()
```

There are some examples on the [sqldf github home page](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#problem_with_no_argument_form_of_sqldf_-_sqldf()).

Another possibility is to use RSQLite directly.

Also note that you could generate a vector of SQL strings and pass the entire vector to sqldf: `sqldf(v)`

Yet another possibility is to use SQLite recursive Common Table Expressions.  Google for more info.

Note that statements other than `select` (such as `create`) result in a warning under RSQLite 2.0 but nevertheless give the correct result so either ignore the warning or use an earlier version of RSQLite.

Comment: Yes, the output shown in EDIT_2 of the question looks correct.